# unexpected end of file when I execute my shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 3 shell scripts

script1.sh

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
   # RETURN INVALID USAGE
   GetBatchCredentials_Result="Error"
   GetBatchCredentials_Reason="Invalid usage: . $0 ApplicationId Alias Logfile"
else
   # CONTINUE PROCESSING WITH PARAMETERSLT
   RSLT=`/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/scripts/script2.sh $1 $2 $3`
   eval "$RSLT";
fi
```

script2.sh

```
# SET UP INFRASTRUCTURE CLASSPATH
. /www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/scripts/script3.sh
PROP="-Dcom.xxxx.env.location.pdc=ITC"
# CALL JAVA GetBatchCredentials TO RETRIEVE THE SERVICE ACCOUNT CREDENTIALS
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $PROP com.xxxx.inf.serviceaccount.batch.GetBatchCredentials $1 $2 $3
```

script3.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/inf-service-account-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf_crypto.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf_generics.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf_password_vault.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf-jmx-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf-utils-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf-env-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf-recovery-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf-throttle-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/inf-trans-2.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/javaee-api-6.0.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/db2jcc.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/db2jcc_license_cu.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_service_account/2.0/dependencies/db2java.zip

export CLASSPATH
```

My lead wants me to combine all these 3 scripts into one, since there is no point in having 3 separate scripts here. These 3 scripts works fine separately, but I first tried to combine first 2 scripts and I am getitng unexpecetd end of file error when I execute this script:

script1+script2.sh

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
   # RETURN INVALID USAGE
   GetBatchCredentials_Result="Error"
   GetBatchCredentials_Reason="Invalid usage: . $0 ApplicationId Alias Logfile"
else
   #SET UP INFRASTRUCTURE CLASSPATH
   . /www/inf/xxxx/inf_security_common/2.0/scripts/script3.sh

   #CALL JAVA GetBatchCredentials TO RETRIEVE THE SERVICE ACCOUNT CREDENTIALS
   RSLT='$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.xxxx.inf.serviceaccount.batch.GetBatchCredentials $1 $2 $3'
   eval "$RSLT";
fi
```

I am running the above scripts using the following script:

testScript.sh

```
. /www/inf/xxxx/inf_security_common/2.0/scripts/GetBatchCredentials.sh SampleBatchAppId xxxxAlias gbc.log
if [ "$GetBatchCredentials_Result" != "Success" ]
then
   echo "Error obtaining FTP Credentials"
   echo $GetBatchCredentials_Reason
   ret=1
else
   echo "Obtained FTP Credentials"
   ########### FTP User ID ################################
   FTP_USR=$GetBatchCredentials_ID
   ########### FTP Password ###############################
   FTP_PWD=$GetBatchCredentials_PW
   echo "starting  FTP" $FTP_USR $FTP_PWD
fi
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: Reproducers need to be **minimal** -- cut down to include only the smallest amount of code needed to produce a given error. This can be as simple as deleting things until the error no longer occurs, undo-ing to keep the one line needed.

Comment: ...there are a bunch of unrelated bugs in here, btw, which the automated tools at http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: (Also, there's no good reason for the use of `eval` here; see BashFAQ #48 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 for notes on why you shouldn't use `eval` unless you have absolutely no other choice).

Comment: I changed the script with the suggestions from shellcheck.net: changed single quotes to double quotes for RSLT. I removed eval. But the error remains.

Comment: See again the advice to use process of elimination: Take things out and incrementally until the error goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly worked, but I deleted and retyped using vim command. And the new file is working. Here is my new file:

```
###############################################################################

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
   # RETURN INVALID USAGE
   GetBatchCredentials_Result="Error"
   GetBatchCredentials_Reason="Invalid usage: . $0 ApplicationId Alias Logfile"
else
   # SET UP INFRASTRUCTURE CLASSPATH
   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/www/inf/xxxx/inf_security_common/2.0/inf-security-common-2.0.jar
   export CLASSPATH

   # TODO - This needs to be set internally.
   PROP="-Dcom.xxxx.env.location.pdc=ITC"
   # CALL JAVA GetBatchCredentials TO RETRIEVE THE SERVICE ACCOUNT CREDENTIALS
   RSLT=`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $PROP com.xxxx.inf.serviceaccount.batch.GetBatchCredentials $1 $2 $3`
   eval "$RSLT";
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RSLT='$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.xxxx.inf.serviceaccount.batch.GetBatchCredentials $1 $2 $3'
```

should be:

```
RSLT=`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java com.xxxx.inf.serviceaccount.batch.GetBatchCredentials $1 $2 $3`
```

You changed the backticks in the original script to single quotes in the combined script.

Another difference. The original `script2.sh` had:

```
PROP="-Dcom.xxxx.env.location.pdc=ITC"
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $PROP com.xxxx.inf.serviceaccount.batch.GetBatchCredentials $1 $2 $3
```

The new script is missing `$PROP` from the call to `java`. It should be:

```
RSLT=`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dcom.xxxx.env.location.pdc=ITC com.xxxx.inf.serviceaccount.batch.GetBatchCredentials $1 $2 $3
```

Comment: I changed that to backticks again. But the error remains the same.

Comment: Found another mistake, you were missing the `$PROP` replacement.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I updated the script. But the error still remains.

Comment: it echo's based on the result from testScript.sh: